# LocalStorage , cookies does NOT work. neither a 500 status or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, header, local-storage

i tried everything to store the token. nothing works.
things i tried: Cookies, headers, localStorage.
basically nothing is defined in authenticate.js so i get a 401.
what am i doing wrong ?

in app.js

```
{authenticate} = require('./public/middleware/authenticate');

// POST /users/login {email, password}
function userLogin(req, res){
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ["email", "password"]);

  User.findByCredentials(body.email, body.password).then(function(user){
     return user.generateAuthToken().then(function(token){
       // res.cookie('authorization', token).send(user);
       res.setHeader('set-cookie',token).send(user);
       // localStorage.setItem('token',token');
       // res.header('x-auth',token).send(user);
        console.log('APP.JS', token);
    });
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.status(400).send();
  });
}
app.post('/users/login', userLogin);
```

in Authenticate.js

```
const {User} = require('.././models/users-Model');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const express = require('express');
const requestCookies = require('request-cookies');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

var authenticate = function(req, res, next){
  // var token = req.cookie.authorization;
  // var token = req.header('x-auth');
  var token = req.header('set-cookie');
  // var token = Cookie('auth');
  // var token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log('authenticate.js',token);
  User.findByToken(token).then(function(user){
    if(!user){
      return Promise.reject();
    }
    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.status(401).send();
  });
}

module.exports = {authenticate};
```

in app.js

```
function listPost(req, res){
  var Data = new budgetCalculator({
    _creator:req.user._id,
    _id: req.body._id,
    firstItem: req.body.firstItem,
    firstPrice: req.body.firstPrice,
    secondItem: req.body.secondItem,
    secondPrice: req.body.secondPrice,
    thirdItem: req.body.thirdItem,
    thirdPrice: req.body.thirdPrice,
    tBudget: req.body.tBudget
  });
  Data.save().then(function(Data){
    return user.generateAuthToken().then(function(token){
      res.header('x-auth',token).send({Data});
    });
    console.log('token', token);
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.send(e)
  });
}
app.post('/', authenticate, listPost);
```

in `users schema file`

```
// generating the token 
// which i use to pass the token 

  UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
    var user = this;
    var access = 'auth';
    var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString(), access}, 'abc123').toString();

    user.tokens.push({access, token});

    return user.save().then(function(){
       return token;
    });
  };
```

its exposed and wired  to other files. i think all i need is to pass the token again when the `listPost` function is fired. so when `authenticate.js` make a `req.header('x-auth)` it receives the same token from `generateAuthToken()`.

but i tried it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Does this two pieces of code are server side ? If yes, it seems that `userLogin` sends a token to the client side, which should set it in the `authenticate` header's request, right ?

Comment: both are server side. i dont use angular or anything yet. i dont get your comment? all the commented codes doesnt work. neither 401 or undefined value of the token. can u clarify more?

Comment: I'll try. So if there're both server side, something requests `userLogin` which respond the `user` object. This response contains the token as a header. Then, you get the user, and you try to authenticate, requesting `authenticate` and passing within the header the token fetch from the previous response's header.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Striped that's exactly what i'm trying to do! the problem is its undefined every time i try to request it. neither setting it as a cookie or a header it's just undefined..

Comment: So can you show us how you retrieve the token from the `userLogin` response and send it to the `authenticate` request, cause I don't see it.

Comment: in app.js `userLogin` function i use `res.header('x-auth',token).send(user);`

and in authenticate.js i use 

`var token = req.header('x-auth');`

which does work in terms of postman. token is defined there but when i try to do something with the app on browser it returns 401.

Comment: Do you understand that the req from `userLogin` and the req from `authenticate` are not the same req, not the same reference ? The header from the `userLogin` is not the header of the `authenticate` ? You can't get the token in `authenticate` because you set it in `userLogin`, **but** because you forward it from the response to the next request.

Comment: how is that ? but its wroking in post man every user has a token and his own data. its also defined but in browser its not working. as i have one of the functions like getting the notes

Comment: in app.js
i edited the post for the function as i cant post it here.
`app.post('/', authenticate, listPost);`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what to say more, in your edit I don't even know from where the variable `token` come from which should be `undefined` I think. All I see is server side code, but nothing about the token passing from the `userLogin` response to another request.

Comment: yes im so sorry. i'm not the best at explaining. i edited it again with proper info. i think there's more to try now. any suggests?

Comment: Still the same issue, you don't show how you pass the token from the `userLogin` response to the `authenticate` request. I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.** 
turns out i was trying to make a `req.cookies.authorization` from `authenticate.js`

```
var authenticate = function(req, res, next){
  var token = req.cookies.authorization;
  console.log('authenticate.js',token);
  User.findByToken(token).then(function(user){
    if(!user){
      return Promise.reject();
    }
    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  }).catch(function(e){
    res.status(401).send();
  });
}
```

when i login using `userLogin` function but when i try to do anything related to the app after logging in i didn't send the same token via `res.cookies.authorization`
resulting in `authenticate.js` to recieve nothing. from the cookies. when i wired every function in the app to send the user token everytime it fires, that fixed the problem.

```
function listPost(req, res){
  var Data = new budgetCalculator({
    _creator:req.user._id,
    _id: req.body._id,
    firstItem: req.body.firstItem,
    firstPrice: req.body.firstPrice,
    secondItem: req.body.secondItem,
    secondPrice: req.body.secondPrice,
    thirdItem: req.body.thirdItem,
    thirdPrice: req.body.thirdPrice,
    tBudget: req.body.tBudget
  });
  Data.save().then(function(Data){
     return Data.generateAuthToken();
  }).then(function(token){
      res.cookie('authorization', token).send({Data}); // this part was missing
      console.log('token', token);
    }).catch(function(e){
    res.send(e)
  });
}
app.post('/', authenticate, listPost);
```